# Error getting data back from google search appliance using any browser other than IE

Tags: jquery, json, google-search-appliance

I have the following html and associated jquery code:

```
<div id="searchFieldDiv">
<input id="searchField" name="search1" type="TEXT"></input>
</div>
<div style="position: relative" id="showdata">
</div>
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
<!--
var loadContextMenu = function (jqXHR, textStatus)
{
    var theJson = jqXHR.responseJSON;
    $('#searchField').autocomplete({
        source: theJson
    });
}

var get_feed_status_json_error = function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert("Got error:  " + jqXHR.responseXML );
};


$("#searchFieldDiv").keyup(function() 
{
  var theString = $("#searchField").val(); 
  var theGoogleBoxURL = "http://url_to_search_appliance/suggest?token="
    +  $("#searchField").val(); 
    var d = $.ajax({
        "url": theGoogleBoxURL,
        "dataType": "json",
        "complete": loadContextMenu,
        "error":  get_feed_status_json_error
  });
});
-->
</script>
```

This code works just fine when I browse using Internet Explorer (version 10).  I start typing into the field searchField and as I do so, ajax requests are sent to my google search appliance which returns json list of possible completions, and these are (in turn) applied to a drop-down below the searchField which allows me to choose one of them to fill out the search field.

Howeveer when I attempt to perform this same task using Firefox, Safari or Chrome, I get an error message:

"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js
Line 4"

I have been googling this error, but for the life of me, I cannot see why it would work on IE, but not on any other browser.  Any help much appreciated.

thanks,

David.

Answer (score 0):

This line would usually come up if the data you are passing is not json, or if the browser fails to automatically encode your data.

Debug through developer tools to see the exact result from your json on chrome, safari an firefox.  Alot of time, the data you are sending will work on  IE, but not on other browsers, or the other way around. You can always use `encodeUriComponent`  in order to encode your data properly if that's the situation.

But the main issue here is, that browsers other then IE aren't getting a json data, or well formatted json.

Comment: thanks heaps for your reply :-)

The odd thing is, if I paste the url of the web-search appliance into the url field on firefox [or any other browser] in the form:

http://url_to_search_appliance/suggest?token=wa

Then it returns valid json text which opens up in notepad.  However when the code runs, I get the error message indicated in the get_feed_status_json_error() method body.

Comment: That's because once the code runs, it fails to encode your json. You have to make sure that the response you are receiving inside to body is a valid json.

Comment: Thanks.  The problem I have is that I am not generating the json - I am [only] receiving it from the google search appliance, and therefore have no control over how the google search appliance responds to my http ajax GET request.  

var d = $.ajax({
        "url": theGoogleBoxURL,
        "dataType": "json",
        "complete": loadContextMenu,
        "error":  get_feed_status_json_error
  });

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I'm trying to nut this out.

My ajax call is:

    var d = $.ajax({
            "url": theGoogleBoxURL,
            "dataType": "json",
            "complete": loadContextMenu,
            "error":  get_feed_status_json_error
      });

I tried leaving out the "dataType" field in the hope that the jquery ajax call would work out what the data is coming back, but that didn't work.  Something that looks very much like json is returned when I manually perform the http get in the browser is what is confusing me.  I don't know where I need to do any encoding or decoding.

Comment: Basically what the error is saying, is that you cannot send a json data type because the data is not a valid json, I got it a lot of time before, when I changed data type to 'text' it worked. What you can try to do, is to use json parse or stringify.  In order to manually parse the json.